# Join 3 tables with 2 where clauses getting null results

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a problem to get result from an sql query. I need result from two where clauses. I work with SQLServer2014

**table1: Product**

```
ProductID
1
2
3
4
5
```

**table2: Supplier**

```
SupplierID
1
2
3
```

**table3: Product_Supplier**

```
ProductSupplierID|ProductID|SupplierID|Reference
1                |1        |1         |Ref001
2                |1        |2         |Ref002
3                |2        |1         |Ref003
4                |3        |2         |Ref004
5                |4        |2         |Ref005
```

What I want to result is when I set:

**where (ProductID<4) and (SupplierID= 2)**

I must get as result: All the product under the ProductID 4 related with SupplierID 2, if this doesn't exist in Product_Supplier, I must get Reference = Null

```
ProductID|SupplierID|Reference
1        |2         |Ref002
2        |2         |Null
3        |2         |Ref004
```

I start some sql script but I can't get the right result

```
select a.ProductID, b.SupplierID, C.Reference from Product as a
  left outer join Product_Supplier as c on c.ProductID= a.ProductID
  left outer join Supplier as B on b.SupplierID = c.SupplierID
where a.ProductID<4 and b.SupplierID=2
```

Answer from Felix Pamittan:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    ps.Reference
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Product 
    CROSS JOIN Supplier
    WHERE
        ProductID < t.ProductID
        AND SupplierID = t.SupplierID
) t
LEFT JOIN Product_Supplier ps
    ON ps.ProductID = t.ProductID
    AND ps.SupplierID = t.SupplierID
```

On this script I can't inject add runtime the where code. When I can set the where on the end of the sql then the enduser can inject the where paramters.

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    ps.Reference
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Product 
    CROSS JOIN Supplier
    --WHERE
    --    ProductID < t.ProductID
    --    AND SupplierID = t.SupplierID
) t
LEFT JOIN Product_Supplier ps
    ON ps.ProductID = t.ProductID
    AND ps.SupplierID = t.SupplierID
where t.ProductID < 4
and t.SupplierID=2
```

I will test this last on the real database.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Product_Supplier WHERE ProductId < 4 AND SupplierID = 2`

Comment: The problem that I can get the second row (2,2,null)

Comment: Just correct me if I'm wrong; there are no tuples in Product_Supplier where the ProductId and SupplierId are both 2... If the tuple isn't there then it will never get selected. That is, when the Product table joins with Product_Supplier, then then SupplierId will be null and likewise for the tuple with SupplierId=2, then ProductId will be null. Your best bet may be a For loop? But that's pretty ugly.

Comment: @JonSick : correct. I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get all the combinations of `Product`s and `Supplier`s first. Do this by doing a `CROSS JOIN`. Finally, do a `LEFT JOIN` on the `Product_Supplier` table:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    ps.Reference
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #Product 
    CROSS JOIN #Supplier
    WHERE
        ProductID < 4
        AND SupplieIrD = 2
) t
LEFT JOIN #Product_Supplier ps
    ON ps.ProductID = t.ProductID
    AND ps.SupplierID = t.SupplieIrD
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/554263)</kbd>

Comment: I think that this is on the right way. Can I also set the where clauses in the t alias?

Comment: What do you mean? I put the `WHERE` clause in the `CROSS JOIN` to minimize the its result before doing a `LEFT JOIN` on the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ps.ProductSupplierID, s.SupplierID, ps.Reference
FROM Product_Supplier ps
   LEFT JOIN Product p ON ps.ProductID = p.ProductID
   LEFT JOIN Supplier s ON ps.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
WHERE p.ProductID < 4
   AND s.SupplierID = 2
```

You may be able to get away with `INNER JOINs` instead of LEFT JOINS, but try the `LEFT JOINS` first and if that works, then give `INNER JOINs` a try just to see. You aren't getting your `Null` values because of your `JOINs` I believe.

**Edit**
The query above should give you your correct results. You need to check and make sure that you really have a record that falls into your category that you think you do. Start by removing some of the `WHERE` clause line by line. When you remove a line of the clause and the record appears, you know that you've found the error.

Comment: That's just my problem, I want to get the null values.

Comment: @Ravaut123 Did the query above not work? That query should give you your null values.

Comment: No, I only change p.ProductID > 4 into p.ProductID < 4. But no null values

Comment: @Ravaut123 Oh, wow. I can't believe I didn't see that you wrote almost the exact query that I gave you. My bad! Let me try something else real quick

Comment: @Ravaut123 Actually, you need to use the query that I wrote above. In your query, you're selecting from the Product table first. You need to be selecting from the Product_Supplier table first and LEFT JOIN your other tables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `b.SupplierID = 2` in the criteria. Because b (Suplier) references to c(link table), it negates the left join in b if the record does not exist in c.

You can move the criterium to the join instead:

```
select a.ProductID, b.SupplierID, C.Reference from Product as a
  join Supplier as B on b.SupplierID = 2 -- moved criterium
  left join Product_Supplier as c on c.ProductID= a.ProductID and c.SupplierID=b.SupplierID   
where a.ProductID<4
```

Since no explicit data of `supplier` is needed, you could also omit that join completely and hardcode '2' in the select part instead (together with having it as an extra criterium in the join)

```
select a.ProductID, 2, C.Reference from Product as a
  left join Product_Supplier as c on c.ProductID= a.ProductID and c.SupplierID=2 -- moved criterium
where a.ProductID<4
```